# How to access TimedText metadata

Tags: android

I'm trying to use the TimedText API from Androids MediaPlayer.  Whenever timed text is to be rendered, I get a callback with a TimedText object.

The TimedText class has 2 public methods:  getText() returning a string with the text, and getBounds() returning a rectangle for the bounding box of the text.

However, when I look into the TimedText.java source file, I find there's a lot more of useful metadata passed inside a TimedText object: color, font, italic, bold, justification etc.  See http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/media/java/android/media/TimedText.java

Unfortunately, all this metadata is private, with no observers to read it.  Is there any other way my application can access this metadata?  I don't see why the mediaplayer adds all this useful data to the TimedText object if the application can't read it.  Anyone experience with using the TimedText class?

Thanks